# Python Panda dataframe - whole row from String to Date

Tags: python, string, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a csv file:

```
Date,2018-07-31,2018-08-31,2018-09-30
Value,12,34,56
```

and then load it into DF with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

Whole first row of dates is taken as a String. How to change values in a first row ('date') to TimeStamp object so that can use function like: `df.columns[0].month`.

How to change the whole first row with for example `to_datetime()` option?

Answer (score 1):

#### Series are *always* columnwise

So you can't set a *row* to a Pandas `datetime` series and use Pandas `datetime` methods on it seamlessly. You can concoct workarounds to convert the row to a `datetime` series *each time you use it*. But that's inefficient and doesn't leverage vectorisation.

You *can* have either your row index or column index as `datetime`.

#### `datetime` index: transpose your dataframe

The cleanest solution is to transpose your dataframe and use a `datetime` index:

```
from io import StringIO

x = StringIO("""Date,2018-07-31,2018-08-31,2018-09-30
Value,12,23,45""")

df = pd.read_csv(x)
df = df.set_index('Date').T
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

print(df)

Date        Value
2018-07-31     12
2018-08-31     23
2018-09-30     45

print(df.index.month)

Int64Index([7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')
```

#### `datetime` columns

If you need columns as `datetime`, you can use `set_index` and then `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df = df.set_index('Date').rename_axis('')
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)

print(df)

       2018-07-31  2018-08-31  2018-09-30

Value          12          23          45

print(df.columns.month)

Int64Index([7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try apply `T` on your DF and then use `pd.to_datetime`

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv').T
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = df.rename(columns={'index':'Date',0:'Value'}).tail(df.shape[0]-1)
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df
         Date Value
1  31/07/2018    12
2  31/08/2018    23
3  30/09/2018    45
```

OR

```
df.T
                1           2           3
Date   31/07/2018  31/08/2018  30/09/2018
Value          12          23          45
```